# Не записывается обьект с масивами после запроса с сервера в react

Tags: reactjs

я пытаюсь получить с сервера обьект с масивами.Он приходит,но я не могу его записать в хуки и отобразить.

```
const [started, setStarted] = useState({
        superVip: [],
        vip: [],
        premium: [],
        standart: [],
}

);
const [startingThisMonth, setStartingThisMonth] = useState({
    superVip: [],
    vip: [],
    premium: [],
    standart: [],
});
const [startingThisWeek, setStartingThisWeek] = useState({
    superVip: [],
    vip: [],
    premium: [],
    standart: [],
});
const [justOpened, setJustOpened] = useState({
    superVip: [],
    vip: [],
    premium: [],
    standart: [],
});
const [startsLater, setStartsLater] = useState({
    superVip: [],
    vip: [],
    premium: [],
    standart: [],
});
const [bonusStarted, setBonusStarted] = useState({
    superVip: [],
    vip: [],
    premium: [],
    standart: [],
});
const [errorStyle, setErrorStyle] = useState({});
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

const get = async () => {
    try {
        const servers = await getServers();
        setKingVip(servers.kingVip || []);
        setSuperVip([servers.superVip || []]);
        setVip([...vip, servers.vip || []]);
        setPremium([...premium, servers.premium || []]);
        setStandart([...standart, servers.standart || []]);
        setJustOpened({
            superVip: [...servers.justOpened.superVip],
            vip: servers.justOpened.vip,
            premium: servers.justOpened.premium,
            standart: servers.justOpened.standart,
        });
        setStarted(servers.timeTested || []);
        setStartingThisWeek(servers.thisWeek || {});
        setStartingThisMonth(servers.thisMonth || {});
        setStartsLater(servers.startLater || {});
        setBonusStarted(servers.bonusStarted || {});
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    } finally {
        setLoading(false);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    get();
    getBanners().then(res => setBanners(res.data));
    getArticles().then(res => setArticles(res.data));
}, []); 
export const getServers = async () => {
   return (await api.get("/servers")).data;
};
```

Код получения данных

Как видите,пробую разные варианты,но ничего не получается,хотя ответ приходит

[image: Вот что возвращает сервер]

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить данную проблему

Comment: Почему вы так решили? Что такое `setKingVip` и ниже следующие сеттеры? Зачем куча useState, если они не используются в приведенном коде?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, где как и что вы проверяете/ожидаете. Но скорее всего нет ожидания await перед get() а это все таки асинхронная функция. Но писать просто `await get()` не поможет, так как колбэчная функция в useEffect не асинхронная, нужно создавать вложенную асинхронную и вызывать ее.

Comment: @DaniilLoban Я предполагаю, что в фукнции get указанные сеттеры не являются сеттерами состояния, а чем то другим. Да и очень странные приведенные сеттеры, там объект с ключами и массивами, а сеттятся массивы. Так что да, вопрос порадил больше вопросов, чем ответов )

Comment: стейты используются для дальнейшей передачи в пропсы.setKingVip это отдельный массив который сортировать не нужно,поэтому он приходит так

Comment: @Konstantin мне кажется проще будет создать минимальный код под вопрос, главное чтобы в нем не было ничего лишнего и воспроизводилась проблема, это увеличит шансы на получение ответа. И нужно будет указать что получаете от кода и что ожидаете от него

Comment: У вас `setKingVip` нигде не объявлен. Такое ощещение, что вы не совсем понимаете, что такое сеттер состояния хука useState.